# Searching in archives

Tags: command-line, bash, virtualbox

Is anyone kindly to help me with this program that i should do in Ubuntu?The program is:
A shell script that identifies a template(pattern) provided as an argument on the command line. The search is also performed in archives. For archives the listing is separate.
Thanks you very much in advance!!

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment. What did you try, and how exactly did it fail to meet the goal?

Comment: Do you want it to search through the contents of the files or just names ? And also do you want to search within directories (a.k.a "Recursive" ) or just the files in the current directory? Please add more information to the post.

Comment: @steeldriver indeed it is a homework

Comment: @ParsaMousavi i want to search just on the current directory and through the contents of the files

Comment: As it stands, it's a poorly posed problem. What exaclty is a "template"? is it a string? a regular expression? something else? is it a single line, or multiple lines? What is an "archive"? A tarfile? a compressed tarfile? a zip archive ... ?

Comment: Can I ask why did you add the virtualbox tag to your question?

Comment: We wont do your homework for you. You can upload what you have tried, and how it has failed, or not quit does as expected. Then maybe someone ca come up with suggestions on how to do it otherwise. But you have to show some effort yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For `Tar` archives you can use :

```
tar -Oxvf ARCHIVE_NAME 2>/dev/null | grep "Some pattern or Regex"
```

Or for searching through all `Tar` files present in the current directory:

```
list=`find . | grep -i "\.tar\." | xargs`


IFS=" " read -ra array <<< $list

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    tar -Oxvf  $i 2>/dev/null | grep "Some pattern or Regex"
done
```

*Important note : if you have tar files with just `.tar` extension , change

```
grep -i "\.tar\."
```

to this :

```
grep -i "\.tar"
```

but be careful that it can cause problems and several errors if you have the pattern `.tar` in the middle of your filenames that actually aren't tar archives.

*Remove `2>/dev/null/` if you want the name of the files to appear above  the contents.

For `Zip` files :

```
unzip -c ARCHIVE_NAME | grep "Some pattern or regex"
```

Or for all `zip` files :

```
list=`find . | grep -i "\.zip" | xargs`


IFS=" " read -ra array <<< $list

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    unzip -c  $i | grep "Some pattern or Regex"
done
```

And for regular files just :

```
grep "Some pattern or regex" * -r
```

to search through all files (and also files within sub-directories).You can also replace `*` with multiple filenames.

If anybody has a better solution , I'm glad to hear it.